# Ruby fails since Yosemite installed

Tags: ruby, macos, vagrant, osx-yosemite

I have not used ruby, vagrant, or rvm since upgrading to Yosemite last fall. But I now need to use Vagrant for a project so I ran the latest package installer and tried to run it. I got an error from ruby. I wasn't sure if rvm or something else had been mangled during the OSX upgrade, so first I tried installing the latest ruby from rvm, but that didn't solve my problem running Vagrant either, so then I uninstalled rvm and all of the rubies it knew. I should be back to plain vanilla OSX ruby. I then tried just testing ruby to see what would happen:

```
$> which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

$> ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.i386-darwin14]
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _ruby_run
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libruby.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _ruby_run
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libruby.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

My problem with trying to run Vagrant seems to be that it looks for ruby at /usr/local/bin/ruby so any rvm ruby is not found and the system ruby is used. What is the dylib reference about? Years ago I installed MacPorts to get postresql, but that did not survive the upgrade either, at least the port command is gone and I've moved all the old files out of the way as suggested on their site as an uninstall. I hope that didn't impact things.

There are a few other questions here on this kind of failure that are similar, but all of them point to solutions that install rvm or MacPorts or HomeBrew or some other third party package. What I want is for the ruby that OSX installed to be available and working as it does on my wife's (non-developer) mac. I'm not a ruby developer, so I don't want to keep up with ruby and friends, I just want the default ruby for this machine to work as it should. If needed I can install rvm or similar later.

Any idea on how/why this is actually messed up? And more importantly, how do I get back to a working state so that ruby runs? Actually, is there a resource that describes how these things are arranged and configured as I suspect that whatever messed this up could show up in other areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system ruby is at

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

The one you are using was probably installed by Homebrew. Check that you have the system ruby in `/usr/bin/` and delete the one at `/usr/local/bin`. You probably have `/usr/local/bin` in your path before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Ah, I moved away the ruby at /usr/local/bin and now my system ruby runs. Oddly enough it was dated 2009, so I don't know where that came from.

I echo'd the PATH at the top of .bashrc and get "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" so it is being set elsewhere?

I removed vagrant and reinstalled it, but it still starts with #!/usr/local/bin/ruby and now just fails for not having a ruby. Anyone running vagrant have an idea on why it does this?

Comment: Oh, it looks like it must be a ruby gems problem. Grrr. Down the rabbit hole I go.

Comment: Vagrant probably has a config file. Your path is not set elsewhere, it says right there "/usr/local/bin:/...." That's why it was looking in /usr/local/bin first and finding a ruby there.

Comment: Yeah, I confused myself thinking that you meant it should have /usr/bin first! :-)  I think that the root problem was that my gems were all messed up. I manually removed the gem command, reinstalled it. Ran it from the place it reported installing to, removed all of the gems I could, then when I re-sourced the shell it magically started working. I suspect that I have a bunch of rotted ruby commands that don't work, but I can root them out later. Vagrant now runs without ruby errors, so I'm good to solve real problems, thanks!

Comment: Just a quick follow-on. I was playing with a ruby IDE last fall and it may have taken over the gems management and put it into an odd state by managing the gems from a different location. Then when I went back to the shell I may have become out of sync at that point.

Comment: Good to know. I use Rubymine and `rvm`. Works great for managing everything.